# How to pass Recycler View Items into one TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get a TextView value item within the RecyclerView. My RecyclerView layout file has two TextViews, one is Product Name and the other for the Quantity as you can see here

=== This is my cart_items_layout_item ===

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/cart_list_product_name"
>     android:layout_width="160dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Product Name"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
>     android:textSize="16sp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>     android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/cart_list_product_quantity"
>     android:layout_width="160dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Product Quantity"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
>     android:textSize="16sp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:gravity="end"
>     android:textStyle="bold"/>
> ```

This is my activity_cart xml

> ```
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
>
> <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>     android:id="@+id/cart_list"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="542dp"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/next"
>     android:layout_below="@id/header_color"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="113dp">
>
> </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
>
>
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/next"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:background="@drawable/button"
>         android:text="CONFIRM ORDER/S"
>         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>         android:layout_margin="10dp" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/sendSMSButton"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/button"
>     android:text="Send"
>     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/smsphoneNumber"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/cart_list"
>     android:text="0918"/>
> ```

This is my RecyclerView Adapter Class

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
            .setQuery(cartListRef.child("User View")
                    .child(Prevalent.CurrentOnlineUsers.getPhone())
                    .child("Products"), Cart.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder 
holder, int i, @NonNull final Cart model) {

                holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getProductName());
                holder.txtProductQuantity.setText("Quantity = " + 
model.getQuantity());

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {

                    CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                            {
                                    "Edit",
                                    "Removed"
                            };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Cart Options");
                        builder.setItems(options, new         
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface 
dialogInterface, int i)
                            {

                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new 
Intent(CartActivity.this, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("pid",model.getPid());
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                if(i == 1)
                                {
                                    cartListRef.child("User View")

.child(Prevalent.CurrentOnlineUsers.getPhone())
                                        .child("Products")
                                        .child(model.getPid())
                                        .removeValue()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull 
Task<Void> task)
                                            {

                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {


Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Item removed successfully", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    //   Intent intent = new 
Intent(CartActivity.this, Home.class);

                                                    // 
startActivity(intent);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });



                                }

                                if(i == 1)
                                {
                                    cartListRef.child("Admin View")

.child(Prevalent.CurrentOnlineUsers.getPhone())
                                            .child("Products")
                                            .child(model.getPid())
                                            .removeValue()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void 
onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                                {

                                                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                    {


Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Item removed successfully", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                        //   Intent intent = 
new Intent(CartActivity.this, Home.class);

                                                        // 
startActivity(intent);
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            });

                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                });


                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_items_layout, 
             parent, false);
                    CartViewHolder holder = new CartViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

=== this is my Cart class/Model ===

```
 public class Cart
 {
private String 
 date,discount,pid,productDesc,productName,productSupplier,quantity,time;

public Cart()
{
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}

public String getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(String pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public String getProductDesc() {
    return productDesc;
}

public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
    this.productDesc = productDesc;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductSupplier() {
    return productSupplier;
}

public void setProductSupplier(String productSupplier) {
    this.productSupplier = productSupplier;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public Cart(String date, String discount, String pid, String productDesc, 
  String productName, String productSupplier, String quantity, String time) 
 {
    this.date = date;
    this.discount = discount;
    this.pid = pid;
    this.productDesc = productDesc;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productSupplier = productSupplier;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.time = time;



}
```

=== CartViewHolder ===

```
   public class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
   View.OnClickListener
 {
     public TextView txtProductName, txtProductQuantity;
     private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

     public CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txtProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_list_product_name);
    txtProductQuantity = 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_list_product_quantity);

}

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view)
 {
    itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);
 }

  public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

}

As you can see in this Image, i use the cart class/model to pass the data to them, then i created another class called CartViewHolder i use this class to set the data into Recycler View. i want to get this values and put it in the message particularly in the SMS. i dont know how to pass it i tried several codes for it.

```
private void sendSmsBySIntent ()
{

    //Want to set specific Phone Number here
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("SET DEFAULT VALUE FOR THIS");
    Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

    //Want to Intent the Items in Here the Product Name and the Quantity
    smsSIntent.putExtra("PUT THE ITEMS HERE");
    try{
        startActivity(smsSIntent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Your sms has failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And what's the problem with the shared code?

Comment: Sorry Already Edit the question, i want to get the data or the values from my recycler view and pass it to the SMS Function so i can send the orders to the specific phone number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you can use your List<Cart> cart model list item to send product and quantity to 
 sms. 



 private void sendSmsBySIntent (Cart model)
 {

    //Want to set specific Phone Number here
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("SET DEFAULT VALUE FOR THIS");
    Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

    smsSIntent.putExtra("pName",model.getProductName());
    smsSIntent.putExtra("pQty",model.getQuantity());

    try{
        startActivity(smsSIntent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Your sms has failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: smsSendToBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               sendSmsBySIntent();
            }
        });

Sorry im new to this programming, i have error in this area when i tried the code above. trying to figure it out. what the problem it says :

sendSmsBySIntent(Cart) in CartActivity cannot be applied to ()

Comment: you have to get specific cart model object which you are passing to adapter of recyclerview

Comment: im still not getting the right code, it says CartActivity cannot be applied to(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference)

Answer (score 0):

You need the list you sent to the adapter. Send it as a parameter to the `sendSmsBySIntent()` function and make a for loop where you build a String.

ie.:

```
private void sendSmsBySIntent (List<Cart> yourList){

    StringBuilder extra = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
        //Build the string the way you want
        extra.append(yourList.get(i).getName()).append(" ").append(yourList.get(i).getQuantity);
    }

    //Want to set specific Phone Number here
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("SET DEFAULT VALUE FOR THIS");
    Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

    //Want to Intent the Items in Here the Product Name and the Quantity
    smsSIntent.putExtra(extra.toString());
    try{
        startActivity(smsSIntent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Your sms has failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Edit:

I changed the function inside `()` , check it.
Now, when you call the function you have to pass the list you are working with. Like so: `sendSmsBySIntent(placeHereYourCartList)`

Comment: Sorry im too confused in sending parameters and list. can you explain a little bit more by code? so i can understand.

Comment: i tried the code, but i cant pass the cartlistRef i made and this is the error message 

"sendSmsBySIntent(java.util.List<com.example.skipgardmobile.Model.Cart>) in CartActivity cannot be applied to(com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference) "

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Can you update your question with your Cart model please?

Comment: Hi, already edit and update the question, i added the Cart Class and CartViewHolder Class in the code above. CartViewHolder is the one responsible for displaying the ProductName and Product Qty, The Cart Class is responsible for getting the data from the firebase database.